# How can I find out the authors of the current commit and its parent commit?

Tags: git

I am currently looking at my old feature branch which has been merged into the master branch by someone else.

After I switched to my feature branch, I found that `git diff master...<my-branch>` showed some changes that I don't think were made by me.

I guess that the person who did the merge made some changes and created a new commit on my feature branch, before making the merge.

So how can I find out the author of the current commit and the author of its parent or  more older ancestor commits?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
> git blame <file>
```

to analyse the authors of each line of any file,

or use:

```
> git log --graph master
```

to analyse the commit graph and the commit authors for the current and old commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'git blame'

[Git Blame Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)

Run 'git blame ' and review the lines that you think have 
changed, or check the dates for latest changes. The abbreviated hash will 
also be available if you want to spelunk the code and checkout previous versions. 'blame' in association with 'git log --name-status' should get you where you want to go.

Comment: Don't forget the second half of the question: *"and the author of its parent or more older ancestor commits"* which git blame won't reveal if the line was changed by the current commit.

Comment: that is where the 'git log --name-status' comes in. 'git blame' provides the current version and hashes, 'git log' lets you review the version, checkout that version and dig akin to a bisection.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the branch you are talking about using `git checkout <branch-name>` and run the command:

```
git log -1 --pretty=medium --stat -p
```

This prints the log of the last commit (the `-1` option, remove it if you want to view more logs) with the author name (`--pretty=medium`. Change it to `--pretty=full` to view more) and the stat of the changes introduced in the commit (the `--stat` option) along with the diff command being applied on the files changed (the `-p` option).